# What would be the safest way to prevent paying unnecessary high gas fees for transferring USDT?

Tags: gas, fees, gas-refund

`Bitfinex` paid a seismic $23.7 million dollars in a gas fee for a comparatively nominal $100K transaction, [link](https://twitter.com/deversifi/status/1442487743922286594).

> At 11:10 UTC on the 27th September a deposit transaction was made
> using a hardware wallet from the main DeversiFi user interface with an
> erroneously high gas fee.https://t.co/OpSHkkFiBo — DeversiFi
> (@deversifi) September 27, 2021

Related [transaction detail on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2c9931793876db33b1a9aad123ad4921dfb9cd5e59dbb78ce78f277759587115).

---

Main question is what is the highest gas fee that can be paid for a simple ETH transfering transaction. If there is no limit what would be the safest way to prevent paying unnecessary high gas fees as a check mechanism?

- If the payment done through `geth` or `metamask` is there any safe check mechanism to prevent paying unnessesary gas?

For BTC transactions [Electrum](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=fee#my-transaction-has-been-unconfirmed-for-a-long-time-what-can-i-do) use `dynamic fees` in order to make sure that the fee you pay with your transaction is adequate. Is there any similiar approach for ETH transactions?

And why is there no `revert()` or refund mechanism on the miners' side to avoid this, where if there is an unnecessary gas fee is paid then refund the unused gas back to users?